# Python index out of range when extrapolating tuple values from a list

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to do the following exercise:

> With the for loop, take the following list and sort it based on the sum of the values of the tuples of the list:
> [(1,5),(9,0),(12,3),(5,4),(13,6),(1,1)]

However, when I write the following code:

```
list1 = [(1,5),(9,0),(12,3),(5,4),(13,6),(1,1)]
tuple1 = [first[0] for first in list1]
tuple2 = [second[1] for second in list1]

list2 = []

for i in tuple1:
    list2.append(tuple1[i] + tuple2[i])
    
print(list2)
```

I keep on getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonExercises.py", line 11, in <module>
    list2.append(tuple1[i] + tuple2[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I need to get the sum between the tuple values then store them in an empty list and sort that list, however, if I apply that method I won't seem to work. Can someone help me? Cheers.

Comment: try to print `i` in for loop and see is that your expected value...

Comment: As an aside, the Pythonic way to sort these by sum is `list1.sort(key=sum)`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here lies in the line `for i in tuple1`.

Your `tuple1` is `[1,9,12,5,13,1]`. When `i=9`, you list is clearly out of range(its length is only 6). Use `for i in range(len(tuple1))` instead.
The full code will be

```
tuple1 = [first[0] for first in list1]
tuple2 = [second[1] for second in list1]

list2 = []

for i in range(len(tuple1)):
    list2.append(tuple1[i] + tuple2[i])
    
print(list2)
```

Comment: Hi, okay I understand what you are saying in terms of where I went wrong besides i=9. How is the loop going to get to i=9? Cheers!

Comment: The reason is, you are looping not through the indices of the list, but through the elements. You loop is essentially `for element in tuple1` (iterates through the elements only )instead of `for index in range(len(tuple1))`(iterates through the indices )

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the elements in the list instead of the indices.

Try this instead:

```
for i in range(len(tuple1)):
    list2.append(tuple1[i] + tuple2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the contents of the tuple instead of the length of the tuple.
add len() function to get the length and use it to iterate. like

```
for i in len(tuple1):
    list2.append(tuple1[i] + tuple2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looping over the elements of the list. You do the same when you are creating the lists `tuple1` and `tuple2` but now you expect a different result.

One way you can do that is with `for i in range(len(tuple1))`.

An other idea is to solve the sum in one line like this:

`tuple_sum = [sum(tuple) for tuple in list1]`

Output:
`[6, 9, 15, 9, 19, 2]`

Now you can sort it:

`tuple_sum.sort()`

Output:
`[2, 6, 9, 9, 15, 19]`